# Sort contents of awk associative array element

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, associative-array

Originally, the file has its contents like this:

```
1.2.3.4: 1,3,4
1.2.3.5: 9,8,7,6
1.2.3.4: 4,5,6
1.2.3.6: 1,1,1
```

after I have tried sorting it incorrectly I have this:

```
1.2.3.4: 1,3,4,4,5,6,
1.2.3.5: 9,8,7,6,
1.2.3.6: 1,1,1,
```

I want to sort it into the following format:

```
1.2.3.4: 1,3,4,5,6
1.2.3.5: 6,7,8,9
1.2.3.6: 1
```

but how do I access each comma-delimited character in each element and sort them uniquely ascending deleting duplicates? The only shell script  I have managed to use so far accesses the whole element only:

```
awk -F' ' 'NF>1{a[$1] = a[$1]$2","}END{for(i in a){print i" "a[i] | "sort -t: -k1 "}}' c.txt
```

Comment: Why is awk being used when simple `sort` can do the job?

Comment: Those 'ip' addresses were in two separate files. I used awk to join them on the ip addresses. The problem is sorting the comma-separated list

Comment: You should show us your process for building the data. Better to fix that than just tack on another process.

Comment: How would I use a simple sort? You could post an alternative answer

Comment: Edit your question to show a sample of your original input and final output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I took the intermediate data as input the first time around, when the original data was not yet posted, but of course it's also possible from the original data. Again with GNU awk:

```
gawk -F '[ ,]' 'BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc" } { for(i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) a[$1][$i]; } END { for(ip in a) { line = ip " "; for(n in a[ip]) { line = line n "," } sub(/,$/, "", line); print line } }' filename
```

The code works as follows:

```
BEGIN { 
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"  # GNU-specific: sorted array
                                          # traversal
}
{
  for(i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) a[$1][$i]      # remember numbers by ip
}
END {                                     # in the end:
  for(ip in a) {                          # for all ips:
    line = ip " "                         # construct the line: IP
    for(n in a[ip]) {                     # numbers in order
      line = line n ","
    }
    sub(/,$/, "", line)                   # remove trailing comma
    print line                            # print the result.
  }
}
```

#### Old answer for intermediate data:

With GNU awk, assuming that the data is formatted precisely as in the question (with a trailing `,`):

```
gawk -F '[ ,]' 'BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc" } { delete a; for(i = 2; i < NF; ++i) a[$i]; line = $1 " "; for(i in a) line = line i ","; sub(/,$/, "", line); print line; }' filename
```

The file contents are split along spaces and commas, then the code works as follows:

```
BEGIN { 
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"  # GNU-specific: sorted array
                                          # traversal, numerically ascending
}
{
  delete a
  for(i = 2; i < NF; ++i) { a[$i] }       # remember the fields in a line.
                                          # duplicates are removed here.
                                          # note that it's < NF instead of
                                          # <= NF because the trailing comma
                                          # leaves us with an empty last
                                          # field.

  line = $1 " "                           # start building line: IP field
  for(i in a) {                           # append numbers separated by
    line = line i ","                     # commas
  }
  sub(/,$/, "", line)                     # remove last trailing comma
  print line                              # print result.
}
```

Comment: Good one! You could probably get rid of the trailing comma by playing with the length of the array. Something like `printf "%d%s", value, (i==length(a) ? "\n" : ",")` could make it. Otherwise, note `print ""` is the same as `printf("\n")`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the trailing comma right after I posted the answer. I opted for building a line string with `sprintf` and removing the last comma before printing to fix that.

Comment: Some distros preinstall mawk. Anyway, it's odd that this shouldn't work if you have GNU awk; there's no very new feature in it. Which version of GNU awk do you have? (`gawk --version | head -1`) should tell you.

Comment: 1.2.3.4: 1,3,
1.2.3.5: 7,8,9,
1.2.3.4: 4,5,
1.2.3.6: 1,

Comment: @Wintermute a[$1] = a[$1]$2","saves all first field in the associative array a, with the key is the first field, the value is second field (or the rest of the line). If the key has already haved value, we concat two values. whereas your code  does not

Comment: Well, we don't really want to concatenate the values right away, do we? They have to be sorted first. And there's no need to remember anything by IP because every line is treated individually. EDIT: Oh, I see, I think. This code assumes the data is in the format that falls out of your original script.